# Merging pull requests together

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Someone has submitted a set of pull requests to my repository on github. Unfortunately they've done this in several pull requests (one for each file) rather than submitting all the pull request for all the files in one go.

After requesting him to merge them as one - and not getting any response I'm now trying to merge these pull requests together myself in the Git Bash - but having little luck - I'm quite happy using the merge buttons and making commits through the GitHub program on windows but little more. I have no real understanding of the git shell - so if someone could go through the process of how I can merge these pull requests together (none of them conflict in anyway) it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Say if you have 3 pull requests A,B,C which are on three branches bA,bB,bC. and your main branch is master.

First get all of his branches to your local repo without merging it.
`git fetch his-repo`

so now your repo may have four branches: `master, bA, bB, bC`

I will create a branch from master called `f-merge-his-repo`

`git checkout master`
This makes sure that f-merge-his-repo branches out from master.

`git checkout -b f-merge-his-repo`
This creates the branch f-merge-his-repo and switch to it.

So now you are currently on f-merge-his-repo, use the following commands:

`git merge bA`

`git merge bB`

`git merge bC`

If there are conflicts you should fix it(manually or using a mergetool), but as you said there are no conflicts, so we say that `bA bB and bC` are now all in `f-merge-his-repo`

then, just simply merge `f-merge-his-repo` into your master branch

You should first switch to the master branch.
`git checkout master`

And then merge f-merge-his-repo
`git merge f-merge-his-repo`

or if you prefer a none fast forward merge
`git merge --no-ff f-merge-his-repo`

After all, delete these branches.

`git branch -d bA`

`git branch -d bB`

`git branch -d bC`

`git branch -d f-merge-his-repo`

You should really take a look at `pro-git` [here](http://git-scm.com/book). It is a simple book which shows you everything you need with git in your daily work, and believe me, once you get used of git bash, you will find all of these git GUI's frustrated(except viewing the log, I use gitk to view and analyse the log)

**Last tip:**

A good way to remember `git merge` and `git rebase` is like

Merge is merging another branch **TO** your current branch (of course you can name both branches, but the default syntax is merge the branch to your current branch)

so you should always switch to the main branch and merge others branch

`git checkout master`

`git merge their-branch --no-ff`
or
`git merge their-branch`

And rebase is rebasing your current branch **ON** another branch(usually the main branch)

`git checkout feature-branch`

`git rebase master`

Comment: right OK I cant find any branches he's made. The only assumption I have is that he must have edited each file one at a time to create the pull requests - rather than doing branches. I've tried cherry-picking the commmits based on more research I've done and also after looking through that book - and all I'm getting is `fatal: bad object xxxxx` where `xxxxx` is the commit number. Any ideas other than to to it all manually?

Comment: Do you mean he first modified a.c and created a pull request, and then based on that version he modified b.c and created another pull request?

Comment: No I mean like he's edited 4 individual files. Rather than creating a pull request. Or at least I can't find any branch that he's tried to merge in. It's these 4 pull requests here if that's any help https://github.com/wilsonge/shoutbox/pulls . I wanna accept them all - but in one merge - so that I can revoke them all in one go if need be/have a more complete log etc.

Comment: I think his branch is `patch-11` `patch-12` `patch-13` `patch-14` you can fetch them all and merge it into one of your own new created branch, and then merge that branch into master. If you only want a single commit on your branch, you may try to look at the interactive rebase, `git rebase -i`

Comment: I tried fetching them all, and just kept getting fatal errors. I've given up and decided to just do it manually as it's just gonna be quicker in the long run. Hopefully won't get any more stupid pull requests like that in the near future!! Thank you very much for your help though!

Comment: Sorry for not actually helping you, but I do STRONGLY recommend you to spend about half a day and read through `pro-git`, after that you will know all you need in your daily work with git(bash).