# trouble merging multiple pull requests from same contributor

Tags: git, github

I received several pull requests from the same contributor. I followed GitHub '[Using Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)' advice and merged his first request without issues:

```
git checkout master
git remote add username git://github.com/username/repo.git
git fetch username
git merge username/pull-request1
```

Before merging the other pull requests from the same person I added some more commits to master, and then pushed. His pull request got automatically closed and I was happy.

Then, today I went on to merge his second pull request.

```
git merge username/pull-request2
```

Merges with no conflicts but the code coming from pull-request2 is not there (some chunks are). After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391421/merging-pull-requests-together), I suspect that committing to master before merging the remaining pull requests was a mistake, but now I'm not sure what to do. Since I pushed to the main repo and other people might have pulled, I cannot go back in time.

EDIT: I just tried with the 3rd request and that one merged just fine. So it must be something related to pull #2 but really, it is just a pull request. I can't see why it shouldn't merge.

Comment: I would look for conflicting changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my findings here, hoping that they can be helpful to other readers.

The only odd thing about that PR was the contributor's branch name, which happened to be `master` like the branch he wanted to merge to. I think that might have been the problem. While investigating I even found a [reference](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/pull-requests-and-other-good-practices-for-teams-using-github/) to this kind of issue:

> When your pull request is merged into the target branch, the
>   maintainer may decide to rebase your commits to avoid a merge commit,
>   or to squash the commits into a single coherent commit. **If your pull
>   request was from your 'master' branch, you will encounter problems
>   when merging the target branch back into your own 'master'**.

We ended up closing the troublesome PR. The contributor then submitted a new one from a different branch, and it merged just fine.